# Integrating Twitter Bootstrap with Smarty

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, smarty

Does anyone have any good practices for adding twitter bootstrap or any front end frameworks to a smarty template. I want a use modular approach so I can use twitter bootstrap along with smartys template inheritance.

Comment: Just want to say include boostrap in your templates and use it as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter bootstrap is a collection of css and javascript files. It does not interact or interfere with smarty templates. That being said, I have personally used bootstrap with my smarty projects with nothing to worry about.